# What's the best way of playing media files (esp. audio) with Mono/C#?

Tags: c#, linux, audio, mono

I'm trying to create something that will be playing some sound and music for some things in Mono+C#, but I'm not sure what the best thing will be for that.

I'm trying to make it usable with things like Ogg Vorbis, MP3s, and wave files.

My primary platform will be Linux, although a cross platform solution would be nice.

Anyone have any suggestions for libraries for playing audio files?

Answer (score 5):

**irrKlang** is a cross platform sound library for C++, C# and all .NET languages

http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/

It is a high level 2D and 3D cross platform (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux) sound engine and audio library which plays WAV, MP3, OGG, FLAC, MOD, XM, IT, S3M and more file formats, and is usable in C++ and all .NET languages (C#, VisualBasic.NET, etc).

**BASS** is an audio library for use in Windows and Mac OSX software. Its purpose is to provide developers with powerful and efficient sample, stream (MP3, MP2, MP1, OGG, WAV, AIFF, custom generated, and more via add-ons), MOD music (XM, IT, S3M, MOD, MTM, UMX), MO3 music (MP3/OGG compressed MODs), and recording functions. All in a tiny DLL, under 100KB* in size.

http://www.un4seen.com/

On Windows, BASS requires DirectX 3 or above for output, and takes advantage of DirectSound and DirectSound3D hardware accelerated drivers, when available. On OSX, BASS uses CoreAudio for output, and OSX 10.3 or above is recommended. Both PowerPC and Intel Macs are supported.

Comment: Unfortunately BASS is non-free!

Comment: The OP didn't specify that they wanted a free solution, although I did provide one free option.

Comment: You are right, but I wrote the comment for people who might also use this as a resource, like myself and others who come after me.